# Blind baking puff pastry

Tags: puff-pastry

Is it possible to blind bake pastry? I am trying out new custard tarts and want to try blind baking puff pastry. Is this possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, is possible, and not uncommon.  You may wish to dock it to prevent excessive rising.

Some pastries are made with puff pastry that is already baked separately, such as the famous [Napolean or Mille-Feuille](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mille-feuille) .  For example, in [this recipe](http://www.dianasdesserts.com/index.cfm/fuseaction/recipes.recipeListing/filter/dianas/recipeID/3084/Recipe.cfm) (which uses commercial puff pastry), the instructions are:

> Preheat oven to 425°F/220°C. Line 2 baking sheets
>   with parchment paper or plain brown paper; set aside.
>
> Unfold puff pastry sheet and trim edges to a 9-inch square. Cut pastry
>   into nine 3-inch squares. Transfer pastry squares to the prepared
>   baking sheets; prick pastry. Bake in a preheated oven for 18-23
>   minutes, or until golden. (Or bake according to package directions.)
>   Carefully remove pastries from baking sheet. Cool on a rack.

I cannot endorse the plain brown paper idea, but the method is fairly standard.

Here is another example, from King Arthur flour, of [croissants du patisserie](http://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/classic-puff-pastry-pate-feuilletee-recipe), which is essentially puff pastry baked as a croissant (as opposed to croissants du boulanger, the baker's croissants, which are yeast raised as well as a laminated pastry).